# PHP comparing boolean with integer

Tags: php, integer, boolean

```
var_dump((int) true); // returns 1
var_dump(true > 0);  // returns true
var_dump(true > - 1); // returns false
var_dump(1 > - 1); // returns true
```

Can somebody explain me in detail what the results of those two above are because it is comparing boolean with integer and it is confusing to me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: this is simply another `php wtf` ... don't ever use `true > -1` or `true > 0`

Comment: `var_dump(true > -1);` **IS FALSE**. 

Why, because PHP converts -1 to boolean, `var_dump((bool)-1);` **IS TRUE**. 

So, if you compare `var_dump(true > true);` what do you get? **FALSE**.

Comment: which of those four in specific is confusing you. And confusing how? I mean what were your expectations? In which point exactly are you being confused?

Answer (score 3):

This answer no longer satisfies the question as OP changed the question.

---

You shouldn't normally compare operands of different types, if you have some code that does this there is probably a mistake. The result may not make a lot of sense.

If you want to know the answer, just try it:

```
var_dump(true > 0); // gives true
var_dump(true > -1); // gives false
```

Comment: what does var_dump mean?

Comment: This does not explain why `true > -1 ` is returning false http://3v4l.org/inJRB

Comment: `var_dump` is a common way to print the contents of a variable, it gives you more info than `echo` and `print`. It doesn't matter what the result of `true > -1` is, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I am trying to understand why

Comment: @tr3quart1sta you should read the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php... though there seems to be a bug

Comment: @KTastrophy, about what bug are you talking about? `true > -1` is `FALSE`˙, that is not a bug...

Comment: @Glavic According to the docs...true should convert to 1 should it not  ?

Comment: @KTastrophy, are you sure that PHP converts `true` to `1`? What if PHP converts `-1` to `true`? Then you get `true > true` which is `false`.

Comment: @KTastrophy - Not sure in the least...just checked that out. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Looks like I can't edit my comment though.

Answer (score 3):

`>` is a numerical comparison operator, so PHP does a ["loose comparison"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and converts `true` to 1 or -1 in each case.

I imagine the following is happening internally:

When you ask if `(true > 0)`, PHP first loosely tests if `true==0`, returns false, then it substitutes 1 for `true` and the comparison returns true.

When you ask if `(true > -1)`, PHP first loosely test if `true==-1`, returns true, which implies `(true > -1)` must be false.

In short: don't do things like this.

Comment: did you test this ?? http://3v4l.org/inJRB

Comment: (true > -1) yields false.

Comment: Why would the test for true == -1 return true?

Comment: @mpaepper because any non-zero number is considered 'true'.

Comment: thanks that is probably it!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what is happening here by considering what Blazemonger has written.
Consider this:

```
var_dump(true == 0); // returns false
var_dump(true == 1); // true
var_dump(true == -1); // true
var_dump(true == -2); // true
```

So true is anything BUT zero.

For the > operator, PHP first tests for equality (==), so
true == X which is always true except for X = 0.
If the comparison yields true, then it cannot be greater, so true > X is always false except for X = 0.

Therefore:

```
var_dump(true > 0); // true
var_dump(true > 1); // false
var_dump(true > -1); // false
var_dump(true > -2); // false
```